# Is there a way on include non-breaking space in csv import to InDesign?

Tags: csv, adobe-indesign

I'm using InDesign's data merge to make playing cards. Is there a way to include non-breaking space in the data? I would like some words to be kept on same lines.

I tried copy pasting non-breaking space from InDesign and web browser to csv file without success. &nbps; doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a dummy string in your source and proceed to a later replacement within InDesign (i.e. ##NBSP## > non breaking space character).

Comment: I believe this is the only way of doing it. I also need to add line breaks the same way. Really clunky though.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Unicode character for nbsp in InDesign: U00A0. If it is anything like the InDesign scripting it should be entered `\u00A0`. or `"\u00A0"`

Comment: This doesn's seem to work. It just adds that string to the text. I guess InDesign escapes the text.

Comment: What encoding is used in the csv file? I get a hunch the problem might be there since this should not be too tricky to fix.

Comment: If you haven't fixed this yet, share some of your csv and I can try to see if its possible to solve.

Comment: I've yet to crack this. I would like to add non breaking spaces, line breaks and bold text somehow with csv and data merge. Here's my csv file. https://www.dropbox.com/s/rjt0us35kso6j7a/Dale%20of%20Merchants%20-%20Cards%20-%20Cards.csv?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

You should combine your copy and paste with Einar's method of Unicode. Meaning, copy a non-breaking space from InDesign and paste it in your CSV file. Then, when you read the CSV file, either via a script or using place option of InDesign, make sure you are using Unicode format while reading the file. That will make sure your unicode characters get preserved because non-breaking space is a unicode character.

I copied and pasted the non-breaking space from Indesign into the CSV file using Brackets. When I placed the InDesign file using the place option, I made sure I used UTF8 reading (in the import options dialog box) and it preserved the space for me.

Is that what you are trying to achieve? Does that help?

Thanks,
Abdul